# Floating li elements with sublist

Tags: html, css, html-lists, floating

I got small problem:

```css
li {width: 50%; float: left;}
ul.sub li {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2
         <ul class="sub">
            <li>Test2.1</li>
            <li>Test2.2</li>
            <li>Test2.3</li>
            <li>Test2.4</li>
            <li>Test2.5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
 </ul>
```

How I can prevent those huge white empty space betwen Test 1 and Test 3 ?
The best option would be that all main li elements would fit into that empty space.

Is that possible? Please HELP!

Comment: I think you wont resolve this just with floats... You can take a look at this plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You can't make two separated `ul` ?

Comment: agree, no CSS only solution, you'd have to use some kind of javascript

Comment: I think it's perfectly expected behaviour - can you draw how would you like to see it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for, but this could be a solution.

```css
li {
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(2){
    float: right;
}
li:nth-child(2) .sub li {
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2
         <ul class="sub">
            <li>Test2.1</li>
            <li>Test2.2</li>
            <li>Test2.3</li>
            <li>Test2.4</li>
            <li>Test2.5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
 </ul>
```

Good Luck'

Answer (score 0):

You can push all the odd `li`'s to the left, and the even ones to the right, after pushing the second `li` to the right, the rest will be forced to stay on the left hand side due to insufficient space :

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {width: 50%; float: left;}
li:nth-child(even) {width: 50%; float: right;}
ul.sub li {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2
         <ul class="sub">
            <li>Test2.1</li>
            <li>Test2.2</li>
            <li>Test2.3</li>
            <li>Test2.4</li>
            <li>Test2.5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are using `odd` and `even` here?

Comment: @RedBreast your answer might also work well in this `<ul>` structure he provided, but ask yourself this: "What if the `<li>` with sub-li's was the 1st `<li>` in the list"

Comment: Ahah, I was exactly wondering the same with your solution. But anyway, however he resolves this, this will always be fairly tricky / easy breakable.

Comment: @RedBreast either way, this solution will still work because the `nth` child is not hard-coded

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing..

```css
ul.sub li {width: 90%; float:right;}
li {width: 50%; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2
         <ul class="sub">
            <li>Test2.1</li>
            <li>Test2.2</li>
            <li>Test2.3</li>
            <li>Test2.4</li>
            <li>Test2.5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add class to `<li>` holding your sub-menu, to avoid hardcoding `li nth` number into CSS. You wouldn't need a class on your sub `ul` then. This would allow you to move `html` of `submenu` around without css depending on its position in markup:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li class="sub">Test 2
         <ul>
            <li>Test2.1</li>
            <li>Test2.2</li>
            <li>Test2.3</li>
            <li>Test2.4</li>
            <li>Test2.5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {width: 50%; float: left;} 
li.sub {float: right;} 
.sub li {width: 100%;}
```